# Find files that were not installed by the package manager

Tags: find, gentoo, symlink

I'd like to get a list of all files in my Gentoo Linux system that were not installed by the package manager (Portage). This is because I want to keep my system as clean as possible, removing all useless files lying around.

Let me tell you what I've tried until now. First of all, I generate the list of all files that belong to some package tracked by Portage:

```
equery files "*" | sort | uniq > portage.txt
```

Then I generate the list of all files on my system, except those that I don't care about:

```
find / \( -path /dev -o -path /proc -o -path /sys -o -path /media \
          -o -path /mnt -o -path /usr/portage -o -path /var/db/pkg \
          -o -path /var/www/localhost/htdocs -o -path /lib64/modules \
          -o -path /usr/src -o -path /var/cache -o -path /home \
          -o -path /root -o -path /run -o -path /var/run -o -path /var/tmp \
          -o -path /var/log -o -path /tmp -o -path /etc/config-archive \
          -o -path /usr/local/portage -o -path /boot \) -prune \
          -o -type f | sort | uniq > all.txt
```

Finally, I get the list of all files that are not tracked by Portage:

```
comm -13 portage.txt all.txt > extra.txt
```

Some statistics:

```
wc -l portage.txt all.txt extra.txt
  127724 portage.txt
   78371 all.txt
    8438 extra.txt
```

As you can see I still get more than eight thousands extra files. I'd like to reduce that number, in order to focus more on files that really need to be deleted.

I noticed that in `extra.txt` there are thousands of files in a small number of directories, such as `/usr/lib64/gcc`, `/usr/lib64/python2.7` and `/usr/lib64/python3.2`. The `/usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.6.3/crtbegin.o` file, for example, is not in `portage.txt` because, in its place, there is `/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.6.3/crtbegin.o`. On my system `/usr/lib` is a symlink to `/usr/lib64`. So it seems that I need to properly handle symlinks to get better results. Perhaps by adding in `portage.txt` all files they point to. I don't really know how to do that.

Also, why `portage.txt` is bigger than `all.txt`? Shouldn't be the opposite since files tracked by Portage are a subset of all files in my system?

Finally, am I forgetting any other location in the `find` command that should be also excluded?

Comment: "This is because I want to keep my system as clean as possible, removing all useless files lying around." — is your own time you've already spent on that cheaper than wasted megabytes of disk space? :)

Comment: Well, I should have said that it's also for finding files that belong to a package that has not been installed via the package manager. I needed a program but no recent ebuild was available, and I have yet to learn how to write ebuilds properly.

Comment: This might be helpful: http://us.generation-nt.com/answer/gentoo-user-how-can-i-find-orphaned-files-help-202679202.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to fix the problem related to symlinks in `portage.txt` by running the following command:

```
equery files '*' | while read i; do readlink -e "${i}"; done | sort | uniq \
       > portage.txt
```

This serves to put in `portage.txt` the files symlinks point to, and not symlinks themselves. It's needed because the `find` command that creates `all.txt` doesn't list any symlink, but just the files they point to, so there would be a lot of false positives otherwise. It's quite a slow command, as it runs `readlink` on thousands of files, but I couldn't find a better solution. Any suggestion is welcome.

Another thing I understood (this was easier) is why `portage.txt` was bigger than `all.txt`. This is mainly due to the fact that I explicitely pruned the `/usr/src` directory and all files beneath from the results of the `find` command, but `equery` listed them regardless.

The last thing I did, even if this was not in the question, was to ignore Python stuff (mostly `__pycache__` files and files with the `.pyc` or `.pyo` suffix):

```
grep '\(\.cpython-32\)\?\.py[co]$\|/__pycache__' candidates.txt \
     > candidates-bytecode.txt
sed -e 's/\(\.cpython-32\)\?\.py[co]$/.py/' \
    -e 's/\/__pycache__//' \
    candidates-bytecode.txt | sort | uniq \
    > candidates-bytecode-source.txt
comm -23 candidates-bytecode-source.txt portage.txt \
     > orphaned-bytecode.txt
```

This way I trace the origin of all Python stuff and check if it's in `portage.txt`. As you can see I wrote the same regular expression two times, one for the `grep` command and the other for the `sed` command, but perhaps it can be done in just a single step.

Comment: It would probably be a *lot* faster, by simply using `cat /var/db/pkg/*/*/CONTENTS | sed -r 's/^... //; s/ ([0-9a-f]+ )[0-9]+$//; s/ -> .*$//'` directly, instead of the amazingly slow Python `equery files '*'`

Answer (score 6):

What you are looking for might be `qfile`. It is part of `app-portage/portage-utils` package and provides option `-o` or `--orphans`.
You can use something like

```
find /usr/bin -type f | xargs -I{} qfile -o {}
```

to get a list of orphaned files in `/usr/bin`.

Remark: Sadly, `qfile` in the current stable version of portage-utils, does not support readin from stdin, and the solution mentioned in the man page of qfile `qfile -o $(find /usr/bin)` does not work if the find result set is large, therefore we have to work around it a little bit, using `xargs`.

BTW, this is not something I myself came up with, but I found it at [gossamer-threads, a comment by yvasilev](http://www.gossamer-threads.com/lists/gentoo/dev/211512#211512).

Comment: Gentoo doesn't use the Debian package manager.

Comment: True. Gentoo uses portage. Like the original question clearly stated. Who wanted to know how to find orphaned files on a Debian system?

Comment: I've changed `find /usr/bin | xargs -I{} qfile -o {}` to `find /usr/bin -type f | xargs -I{} qfile -o {}`, because without `-type f` in the find command qfile would also check all the symlinks, which normally don't belong to any packages...

Answer (score 0):

IIRC, gentoo stores package info in plain text (/var/db/ perhaps), direct searching can be slow.

The best way of doing so, is create a sqlitedatabase (or whatever db) for all package files, then list all files on your system, look them up in the db one by one, if not found, it doesn't belong to portage.