# Find files not installed by RPM package manager

Tags: fedora, yum, rpm, dnf

Is there some way to find out ***all*** the files on a given system that *weren't* installed via RPM? I understand that I can brute force this myself using something like `rpmquery -f` in a script that loops through all files in the file system, however I was wondering if there is some standard way to do this for RPM based systems (specifically Fedora, which I use at home). Since this for Fedora, it is fine to use `yum` or `dnf` to figure this out.

If there is no standard way to do it, does anyone know of some pre-existing scripts to do this? I don't want to re-invent the wheel if I don't need to.

P.S. [There is another question similar to this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/51823/find-files-that-were-not-installed-by-the-package-manager), but it is about Gentoo and Portage, so it isn't totally relevant.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what would be the actual use case?

Comment: @doktor5000 I have a home desktop that I have added a fair amount of 3rd party software to over the past couple of years. Instead of trying to track down by hand every single file I installed outside of rpm, it would be nice to get a list of those files so I would know what to copy over manually, reinstall when I update my system, or simply ignore. I have bad luck when trying in place upgrades if Fedora, so I tend to reinstall totally fresh.

Comment: Well then maybe it would be easier to first limit yourself to rpm packages that don't come with the base repositories. Also, other software is commonly installed to /usr/local by default or into /opt which should be pretty easy to check as that is not used by normal distro packages. For standard paths like /usr/bin, /usr/share or /usr/lib and similar you would probably need to resort to one of the scriptlet methods as linked in my answer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

a bit late to the party, but hopefully someone will find this useful:

```bash
find /usr/ -exec /bin/sh -c 'rpm -qf -- "$1" >/dev/null 2>&1 || echo "$1"' find_sh {} \;
```

This command crawls over the file system, and runs `rpm -qf` on it. `rpm -qf` prints the corresponding package for a file, and luckily has a return value of 0 if it finds one and 1 otherwise.

If you're brave, you can tie the output to `| xargs rm -f`, but personally I wouldn't be so brave. Turns out there's a lot of stuff in `/usr` that's not really owned by anything.

Answer (score 7):

Per https://superuser.com/questions/555918/how-do-i-list-all-the-files-not-owned-by-any-package-in-a-rpm-based-system, the following command is a solid baseline for what you need:

`comm -13 <(rpm -qla | sort) <(find / -type f | sort)`

Customize further by filtering the find command to directories of interest (either specifying the list of directories instead of `/` (e.g. `/{usr,bin}`) or excluding folders like `/proc`, `/dev`, `/home`, and `/tmp`.

Comment: More exhaustively: `comm -13 <(rpm -qla | sort | uniq) <(find / -xdev \( -type f -o -type d -o -type l \) | sort) `

This lists (`-l`) the files in all installed packages (`rpm -qa`) and sorts them then removes duplicates (because some directories are supplied by multiple packages). It also finds all files on the root partition (without going into other filesystems - `-xdev`) and returns all files, directories and symlinks (`\( -type f -o -type d -o -type l \)`). It then uses `comm` to compare, ignoring the entries only in the rpm list (`-1`) and the entries in both (`-3`).

Comment: Also note that you might need to use `sudo` on the find so that you can find files (especially under /etc) that only root can access.

Answer (score 3):

As far as I'm aware, this is not possible with some kind of dedicated command, only via a little scripting. *TL;DR - see the links at the bottom.* And for rpm-based systems or other binary-based package managers this doesn't make much sense. Such package managers are usually state-based machines intended to keep track of the things that they install themselves, and not to know everything that users sneak onto the system "behind the back" of the package manager.

Where would you draw the line for files that are not owned by rpm files? What about temporary files ( think /tmp and /var/tmp ) or caches ( think /var/cache ) or files created by a user ( /home or /srv or other user-defined mountpoints ).

For source-based distros it might make sense to offer that functionality if the use case limits them to [FHS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_Hierarchy_Standard) directories used by "system" packages like /usr, /bin, /lib and similar, as opposed to e.g. /usr/local or /opt for 3rd party software.

---

See the following similar questions for scriptlets to do what you asked for:

- [How do I list all the files not owned by any package in a RPM-based
  system?](https://superuser.com/questions/555918/how-do-i-list-all-the-files-not-owned-by-any-package-in-a-rpm-based-system)
- [Mailing list thread: Clever way to find ALL files not owned by
  RPM?](https://www.redhat.com/archives/rpm-list/2006-May/msg00096.html)